# Get result from 3 table with 2 column matching mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables something like this..

```
Table1.
group_id        admin
................
1         x
2         y
3         z

Table2
group_id        user
....................
1               a
1               b
2               d

Table3
user            status
......................
x               hi
y               hello
z               oh
a               oho
b               sss
d               oops
```

now you can see that in the above tables we have `group id` but in the first table i have group admin and second one contains group members..
and following is the result which we want something like this in which both `group admin` as well as `group members` we want from a signle group.

```
group_id        user          status
....................................
1               x             hi
1               a             oho
1               b             sss
```

So,,,Help us to get result something like above.. in `mysql`

Comment: Union table 1 2 and join to 3

Comment: learn how to use [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s?

Answer (score 0):

If you think of data in terms of data sets...

you have data in tables 1 and 2 that match in columns but you need them together.  So using a UNION statement you can combine the two tables, alias the result set and join it to your third table to get the desired results.

This generates a derived table aka inline view (aliased t2)

```
SELECT T2.Group_ID, T2.user, T3.Status
FROM (SELECT group_ID, Admin as user 
      FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT group_ID, user 
      FROM table2
     ) t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3
 on t3.group_Id = T2.GroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
SELECT table1.group_id, table3.user, table3.status 
FROM Table1, table2
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table1.admin = table3.user OR table2.user = table3.user)
WHERE table1.group_id = table2.group_id AND table1.group_id = 1
GROUP BY table3.user
```

I am assuming every group has an admin and every user has an entry in table 3.